# How can I access the internet in a way that proves my physical location?

Tags: ip, geolocation

Perhaps the opposite of an information security question:

1. Consider a hypothetical where my associate and I have been accused of being the same person abusing multiple accounts on an online forum.
2. Administrators have the power to look up the IP addresses of users.
3. My associate and I are on different continents.

With the internet access options available to the average individual in CONUS and SE Asia (mobile, coffee bar, public library, etc.), and without revealing any personal information other than our IPs, how can my friend and I simultaneously access the internet to prove to someone with a modicum of investigative power that we are, within a high degree of certainty, not using proxies/VPNs/etc., and are separate people at separate locations?

Put another way: there are many methods for disguising your true location when accessing the internet. How can I access the internet in a way that greatly narrows down the number of places I could be, preferably to one?

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

Internet access alone cannot prove physical location of the person. For instance, this person may use remote access tools like TeamViewer or LogMeIn to access devices at different locations.

Even if administrators could check that the IP is neither VPN provider nor a Tor exit node, there is no way for administrators to check that remote access tools are not used. IP and any other information like time zone in browser may be typical to particular location. But this does not say anything about the physical location of the person that uses this device.

Comment: Two laptops on two separate airlines would suggest the physical presence of two people, unless we're assuming those laptops checked themselves in and waited until 10,000 feet to hop up on the tray table. I don't know if that activity would be identifiable to an airline, but I am asking for a *little* imagination.

Comment: Or that you have malware running on two travellers laptops. The answer's still no.

Comment: @clyf how does that scenario apply? How do the admins of the forum prove that that scenario is true? And that isn't relevant to what you've asked about accessing the internet to prove physical location. It's starting to look like you don't have a clear problem statement and you are looking for a solution that "looks right" for some other criteria other than what you've expressed. Are you trying to write a story?

Comment: Believe it or not I am not trying to write a story. My apologies for any confusion, but this is the direct question (center removed for char count):

"With the internet access options available to the average individual in CONUS and SE Asia...and are separate people at separate locations?"

"Prove physical location" was a shorthand summary of the above with the goal of avoiding an overly chunky title. "Proof" in this case as in "people believe it", not "mathematical".

Comment: I just don't think "I infected two travellers laptops with malware knowing they would be on separate flights at the same time, *and* would both access the internet on said flight" passes the feasibility test for the relatively low stakes we're talking about here.

Comment: An assumption I didn't express was that some IP addresses are stickier than others (GoGo Inflight would be an example) and in some cases overlap with other aspects of the location (like being on a plane) that make the presence of a physical operator extremely likely. I didn't want to state those assumptions because my knowledge of IP routing and detection is limited, which is why I'm here.

Comment: @clyf: *"Two laptops on two separate airlines..."* - Nope. As I wrote, you can use TeamViewer, LogMeIn, AnyDesk or any other similar remote desktop software. You can be sitting **at home** and accessing 2 laptops of 2 persons on 2 airlines (let say, your friends, colleagues, smb. else who trusts you and allow to access their laptops). If they access virtual machines on their laptops, then they don't even need to trust you, because it is relatively safe. The IPs and browser requests that forum admins see in the logs **don't prove anything** about your location.

Comment: @clyf: *"An assumption I didn't express was that some IP addresses are stickier than others"* - This doesn't matter at all. The form admins see just IP. They don't know is there is someone sitting at the laptop of if somebody accesses this laptop remotely.

Comment: @clyf: I am not sure if you know what remote desktop tools are. I'd suggest you to try. Briefly, it may look as following. From your laptop in US you are accessing remotely the laptop of your friend that is currently in France. Then from his laptop you access the website. The website will see that requests come from France. But you are in the US, not in France. Same about airlines. The website can only know where the laptop is, not where the person is who may access this laptop from another laptop remotely.

Comment: "You can be sitting at home and accessing 2 laptops of 2 persons on 2 airlines (let say, your friends, colleagues, smb. else who trusts you and allow to access their laptops)."

There's still three living, breathing humans involved in this process.

I'm familiar with the concept of remote desktop tools, yes. I think what's being lost here is that there's no identity attached to the account, so I'm not trying to prove anything other than there is more than one person involved in process, and the 2+ individuals are not in the same place. Two airlines fit the bill but it's way out of scope.

Comment: *"I'm not trying to prove anything other than there is more than one person involved in process"* - This doesn't prove that there is more than one person involved. You can put 10 laptops in 10 different cities or countries and access them from a single place. These 10 laptops don't prove that there is more than one person. Or you can develop some malware that allows you to access Internet via laptops of other people.

Comment: We can't devise a solution that would pass a believability test for an arbitrary person. We can't only provide a technical analysis. Anyone with any knowledge of networking will not be able to comfortable believing that any IP (for, that's what you've said they only have to go on) ***must*** mean that that user account is in that location. Period. And since this isn't for a story, then we can't delve into improbable scenarios, like IPs anchored to very specific high-security locales.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to fool an investigating person into thinking you are not using a kind of tunneling (proxy/vpn) without actually getting tracked.

Unless it is law enforcement which will knock on your door to verify if you live at the location indicated by your IP-address the average person won't be able to verify with 100% certainty that you are not using a proxy/vpn.

But depending on your situation you could try to leave forged breadcrumbs of evidence about where you are located. For example: Images often contain metadata like the coordinates of the location where they were captured. [McAfee got tracked by this](https://www.wired.com/2012/12/oops-did-vice-just-give-away-john-mcafees-location-with-this-photo/). Use something like ExifTool to edit the metadata to your location of choice and upload it on the forum or whatever site you're using.

If someone chooses to investigate that image and the website in question doesn't trim the metadata by default, he will see your modified location and suspect you have taken the image from there.